# Android: I get an error inserting a date in SQLite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

It's not quite an error but a problem.
I do not receive any errors, nor the app crashes. All works fine except, when I download the db to my PC and access it with KiSQLite, the date I inserted in the table appears as "Invalid date".
I tried 2 ways:
1.

```
public void SaveInfo(String value){
        SQLiteDatabase mDatabase = new myDbHelper(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase();
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        Date date = new Date();
        String dt = dateFormat.format(date);
        mDatabase.execSQL("insert into mytableinfo(datakm,km) values ('"+dt+"',"+value+")");
        mDatabase.close();
    }
```

2.

```
public void SaveInfo(String value){
        SQLiteDatabase mDatabase = new myDbHelper(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase();
        mDatabase.execSQL("insert into mytableinfo(datakm,km) values (datetime(),"+value+")");
        mDatabase.close();
    }
```

All I want to do is insert a record in that table, with a date of today (now) and another value.

How should I do it?
Both methods seem to insert Invalid date values...

Please help
Thank you

**EDIT**
This is my table declaration

```
sqlu = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_PARCURS + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                PARC_DATA + " DATE NOT NULL, " +
                PARC_KM + " TEXT) ";
        Log.e("CREATE tbl:", sqlu);
        db.execSQL(sqlu);
```

Is it wrong? Should I declare the date as TEXT instead of DATE?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
String mydate = dateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Comment: I don't think it's the way I get the date. Maybe it's the way I insert it..?!?!?

Comment: So then do one thing. just print the date in log before storing into database.

Comment: I did what you asked, still Invalid date. Here are the log lines:` 04-24 13:10:46.860    9706-9706/ro.myapp.app E/MyDATE:﹕ 2014-04-24 13:10:46

Comment: I also logged the text of the insert : 04-24 13:10:46.880    9706-9706/ro.myapp.app E/MyDATE INSERT:﹕ insert into parcurs(datakm,km) values ('2014-04-24 13:10:46',23434534)`

Comment: And like I said... the date ends up invalid in the table

Answer (score 0):

i cant tell what wrong in your code but you might do it like i do.

```
   ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();

    // Assign values for each row.
    newValues.put(Constants.EVENT_TYPE_ID, event.getEvent_type_id().getId());
    newValues.put(Constants.EVENT_TITLE, event.getEvent_title());
    newValues.put(Constants.EVENT_TEXT, event.getEvent_text());
    newValues.put(Constants.EVENT_DATE, event.getEvent_date());
    newValues.put(Constants.CREATE_DATE, event.getCreate_date());
    newValues.put(Constants.EVENT_PIC, event.getEvent_pic());
    newValues.put(Constants.EVENT_DISPLAY_DATE, event.getDisplay_date());
    newValues.put(Constants.EVENT_INTERVAL, 0.0);
    newValues.put(Constants.EVENT_SONG, "");
    newValues.put(Constants.EVENT_VIDEO, "");
    long numOfCulm = myDataBase.insert(Constants.TABLE_EVENTS, null, newValues);
```

Constants - is my class where i save all the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the solution to my problem is to declare the date field as TEXT and insert formatted date in the field. Apparently, the SQLite/Android will treat the TEXT field like DATE if I do so.

So, table declaration will be :

```
sqlu = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_PARCURS + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                PARC_DATA + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + // <-- here is what I changed
                PARC_KM + " TEXT) ";
        Log.e("CREATE tbl:", sqlu);
        db.execSQL(sqlu);
```

And insert code will be the same (with formatted date)

Later I can query the table using DATE utils like

```
SELECT * FROM table where date(datakm)=date(datetime())
```

*(this will return all the rows in the table that have the current date in datakm field)*

So basically, my problem is solved.
Thanks for your time, but I found the solution myself. I wrote the solution as an answer so that other developers that have this issue will have a solution to their problem.
Good luck